# Why is adapter context the application and not the activity?

Tags: android

I noticed the context within my adapter is MyMovieApp, not SelectActivity:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Movie movie = getItem(position);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    /* convertView will be null if convertView isn't from recycler
     * the last earlier row isn't totally out of view when scrolling
     */
    if(convertView == null) {
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "convertView is null; Position=" + position + " and " +
              " movie=" + movie.getTitle());
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection_item, parent, false);

        // inflate individual views and cache them into viewholder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        viewHolder.cb.setChecked(movie.isSelected());

        viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

                //allMovies.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                Movie selectedMovie = allMovies.get(getPosition);
                selectedMovie.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                //movie.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                Log.d("SELECT", "onCheckChanged, " + selectedMovie.getTitle() + " is " + buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });

        viewHolder.posterIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.ivMoviePoster));
        viewHolder.playBtnIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.ivPlayBtn));
        viewHolder.movieTitleTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        viewHolder.castTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.topCast);
        viewHolder.ratingTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.rating));
        viewHolder.runtimeTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movlength);
        viewHolder.showtimesNSGV = (NonScrollableGridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.showtimes);

        // TAG - associate view memory with these views
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        // TAG - associate view memory with checkbox, unnecessary
        convertView.setTag(R.id.cb, viewHolder.cb);

    }
    else {
        Log.d("SELECT_ADAPTER", "Reusing convertView, position=" + position + "and " +
               " movie=" + movie.getTitle());
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // AND TAG HERE
    viewHolder.cb.setTag(position);

    viewHolder.cb.setChecked(allMovies.get(position).isSelected());

    // associate play button with movie so listener callback knows which trailer to launch
    viewHolder.playBtnIV.setTag(movie);

    // set values in views
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movie.getImageUrl(), viewHolder.posterIV);
    viewHolder.movieTitleTV.setText(movie.getTitle());
    viewHolder.castTV.setText(movie.getTopCast());
    viewHolder.ratingTV.setText(movie.getRating());
    viewHolder.runtimeTV.setText(movie.getDuration());

    ArrayList<String> showtimes = movie.getShowtimes();
    showtimes = getTwelveHrShowtimes(showtimes);
    ArrayAdapter<String> gridAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.gridview_item, showtimes);
    viewHolder.showtimesNSGV.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    return convertView;
}
```

logcat says: Could not find a method playTrailer(View) in the activity class com.example.apps.MyMovieApp for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'ivPlayBtn'

the xml for the selection item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="1.9"
    android:scaleY="1.9"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/posterLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cb"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cb">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMoviePoster"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/poster_border" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPlayBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        android:onClick="playTrailer" />
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/movie_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/posterLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topCast"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/posterLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/movie_title"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/posterLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/topCast"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/movlength"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/posterLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/rating"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<!--  match_parent width means match the parent(RelativeLayout) width;
      fill out rest of screen.  Versus wrap_content on height means the grid should only
      be as high as the results it contains -->
<com.sb.android.widget.NonScrollableGridView
    android:id="@+id/showtimes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/posterLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cb"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name=".MyMovieApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".SelectActivity"
        android:label="Select Desired Movies"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/poss_sched">
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Without code, it will be difficult to help you. Are you inflating the "listview item" yourself? If so, how are you doing that?

Comment: Please paste the log cat here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `LayoutInflater.from(getContext());` with `getLayoutInflater()` called on your `Activity`.

Comment: this is not in my activity, this is in my adapter because the xml im inflating here, the play button is a selection item.

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA: That does not matter. Create your `LayoutInflater` by calling `getLayoutInflater()` on your `Activity`. How you choose to accomplish that is up to you. Some developers make the adapter be an inner class of the activity. You could pass in the `LayoutInflater` to the adapter's constructor, or provide it via a setter method.

Comment: thanks, I think that would work.  I fixed it by passing SelectActivity.this in as the context instead of getApplicationContext(), which I guess always gives the Application instance.

Comment: ANOTHER INTERESTING NOTE: passing in the wrong context, in this case application context actually changed the text color from black to light gray, probably because the application them was defined as "android:theme.Light"

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA: You may be interested in [this blog post from Dave Smith](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) describing the roles of different types of `Context`.